# Why is Sphinx READ THE DOCS not updating from our GitHub?

Tags: github, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

We have Sphinx READ THE DOCS for our TorahBibleCodes GitHub project presented at the following link:

https://torahbiblecodes-sphinx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

The source code for display of the above page is hosted here:

https://github.com/TorahBibleCodes/TorahBibleCodes_Sphinx/blob/main/docs/source/usage.rst

We need to update this documentation, but it is not updating no matter how much we change the source code that is hosted on GitHub.

We thought that maybe it was an issue of access tokens, so we updated the tokens, and yet still the READ THE DOCS page that is hosted is not updating.

We do not understand the reason why changes in the GitHub are not being displayed at the Sphinx ReadTheDocs.io.

We have waited all day in case of any delays in the propagations of changes, but still no updates on the READ THE DOCS page.

Comment: And you can confirm you've run through every step in https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/index.html correctly? (And don't answer that immediately, actually confirm each and every step there, then update your post once you've done that to explain that, and how, you've verified you did things correctly)

Comment: You appear to be missing a .readthedocs.yaml file in this directory: https://github.com/TorahBibleCodes/TorahBibleCodes_Sphinx/

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and help. Nick, we have changed nothing from July when we first created this documentation, and everything worked and updated fine.

Answer (score 1):

Always check the build log, and it becomes obvious.

https://readthedocs.org/projects/torahbiblecodes-sphinx/builds/21820743/

> ### Error
>
> The configuration file required to build documentation is missing from your project. Add a configuration file to your project to make it build successfully. Read more at https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html